# Attach screenshot to failed test cases in junit report

Tags: eclipse, ant, junit, selenium-webdriver

i need to attach screenshot of the failed testcases in junit report.
What changes are neede to be done in in the "junit-frames.xsl" file.
Please do advice
[image: Junit report]